# How to draw the curves in an energy diagram in R?

Tags: r, diagram, curve, energy

I wrote following R script:

```
#energy diagram
x <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9 )    #chosen randomly, reaction axis
y <- c(-5.057920, -5.057859, -5.057887,-5.057674, -5.057919 ) #energy of the educt, intermediate, transtition states and product 
plot(x,y, type="p",
     xlim=c(0,1),
     ylim=c(-5.058,-5.0575),
     xlab="reaction axis",
     ylab=expression(paste(E[el] ," / ",10^6," ",kJ/mol)),
     xaxt="n"        #hide x-axis
     )
#h- and v-lines, so i can draw curves by hand
abline(v=seq(0,1,0.1),h=seq(-5.0600,-5.0500,0.00005),col="black",lty=1,lwd=1)
abline(h=c(-5.057920, -5.057859, -5.057887,-5.057674), col="blue", lty=1,lwd=0.7)
```

Is it possible to draw a curve through the points that would look like a energy diagram. An example of an energy diagram is here: [image: Energy diagram as an example]

Comment: `lines(spline(x, y))` gives unfortunately a bad fit.

Comment: So you what you provide is the min/max (x,y) pairs, which means you want to fit a curve through those points where the derivative is 0 at those points. Splines could be used for this, but I don't know of any standard R implementations that also let you specify the derivatives. You might have more luck with Bezier curves from the `bezier` package. This will let you add "control points" horizontally from your min/max points which will enforce a 0 derivative at the min/max points.

Comment: Looking a little more, `Hmisc::bezier` seems easier to use. I don't have much time now but can work up a solution in a day or so if it's still needed.

Comment: It's ok, I'll read myself into bezier. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot could be done to streamline / vectorize this code, but for a smallish diagram this works pretty well:

```
# get that data
x <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9 )    # reaction axis
y <- c(-5.057920, -5.057859, -5.057887,-5.057674, -5.057919 ) # energies
```

I'm going to make a little Bezier curve to connect each point to the next---this way we can make sure the smooth line passes through the data, not just close to it. I'll give each point a single 'control point' to define the slope. By using the same y-values for a point and it's control point, the slope at the point will be 0. I'll call the offset between the point and the control point `delta`. We'll start with one point-pair:

```
library(Hmisc)
delta = 0.15
bezx = c(0.1, 0.1 + delta, 0.3 - delta, 0.3)
bezy = rep(y[1:2], each = 2)
plot(bezx, bezy, type = 'b', col = "gray80")
lines(bezier(bezx, bezy), lwd = 2, col = "firebrick4")
```

Here I plotted the points and control points in gray, and the smooth line in red so we can see what's going on.
It looks promising, let's turn it into a function that we can apply to each pair of points:

```
bezf = function(x1, x2, y1, y2, delta = 0.15) {
    bezier(x = c(x1, x1 + delta, x2 - delta, x2), y = c(y1, y1, y2, y2))
}
```

You can play with the `delta` parameter, I think 0.1 looks pretty good.

```
plot(x, y, xlab = "Reaction coordinate", ylab = "E", axes = F)
box(bty = "L")
axis(side = 2)
for(i in 1:(length(x) - 1)) {
    lines(bezf(x1 = x[i], x2 = x[i + 1], y1 = y[i], y2 = y[i + 1], delta = 0.1))
}
```

You can of course tweak the plot, add labels, and `ablines` as in your original. (Use my `for` loop with the `lines` command to draw only the smoothed lines.) I  left the points on to show that we are passing through them, not just getting close.

[image: Bezier example]

I prefer plotting in ggplot2, if you do too you'll need to extract the data into a data.frame:

```
bezlist = list()
for (i in 1:(length(x) - 1)) {
    bezlist[[i]] = bezf(x1 = x[i], x2 = x[i + 1], y1 = y[i], y2 = y[i + 1], delta = 0.1)
}


xx = unlist(lapply(bezlist, FUN = '[', 'y'))
yy = unlist(lapply(bezlist, FUN = '[', 'y'))

bezdat = data.frame(react = xx, E = yy)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bezdat, aes(x = react, y = E)) + 
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Reaction coordinate")
```

Comment: Gregor you bloody genius, you just saved me hours of frustrating research :). I learned about `ggplot2` a few weeks ago, I still need to learn how to handle it though. Anyway, I really really appreciate your effort! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use a spline fit. Define some points along the energy diagram, and then fit to them using a spline function. The more points that you provide, the better that your fit will be. You can check out the smooth.splines function in the stats package for one implementation of the spline fit.

Comment: I added following commands to my script: `smoothingSpline = smooth.spline(x, y)` and `lines(smoothingSpline)`. It doesn't fit though. The line is defined throught the five given points which are local minima and maxima.